# Objects in Multiprocess Shared Memory?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a set of objects states which is greater than I think it would be reasonable to thread or process at a 1:1 basis, let's say it looks like this

```
class SubState(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.stat_1 = None
        self.stat_2 = None
        self.list_1 = []

class State(object): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.my_sub_states = {'a': SubState(), 'b': SubState(), 'c': SubState()}
```

What I'd like to do is to make each of the `sub_states` to the `self.my_sub_states` keys shared, and simply access them by grabbing a single lock for the entire sub-state - i.e. `self.locks={'a': multiprocessing.Lock(), 'b': multiprocessing.Lock()` etc. and then release it when I'm done. Is there a class I can inherit to share an entire SubState object with a single Lock?

The actually process workers would be pulling tasks from a `queue` (I can't pass the sub_states as args into the process because they don't know which sub_state they need until they get the next task).

---

Edit: also I'd prefer not to use a manager - manager's are atrociously slow (I haven't done the benchmarks but I'm inclined to think an in memory database would work faster than a manager if it came down to it).

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to have unrestricted access to `self.locks` (so everyone can read from it in parallel) and a single lock around `self.sub_states` to prevent concurrent writing or no lock around `self.sub_states` either?

Comment: @SeanVieira Yes, unless I'm incorrect child processes (workers) will inherit self.locks as shared-memory copy from the parent (actually not sure how multiprocessing.Locks() is implemented at the low level). I don't have any good ideas for how to share the SubState objects though.

Answer (score 2):

As the [`multiprocessing` docs state](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), you've really only got two options for actually sharing state between `multiprocessing.Process` instances (at least without going to third-party options - e.g. redis):

1. Use a `Manager`
2. Use `multiprocessing.sharedctypes`

A `Manager` will allow you to share pure Python objects, but as you pointed out, both read and write access to objects being shared this way is quite slow.

`multiprocessing.sharedctypes` will use actual shared memory, but you're limited to sharing `ctypes` objects. So you'd need to convert your `SubState` object to a `ctypes.Struct`. Also of note is that each `multiprocessing.sharedctypes` object has its own lock built-in, so you can synchronize access to each object by taking that lock explicitly before operating on it.

Comment: Is there an effective way to pass reference to newly created `ctypes` (it sounds like I'll have a signaling problem then too - one could use a manager or a shared hash table to keep track of all of the shared `c.structs` but it's not too pretty) I'm really leaning towards Redis - and rewriting parts of the code in C if Redis proves too slow.

Comment: @user3467349 Just to clarify, you need to create and share new objects after child processes have already been created?

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that - but not very clearly in the question it seems, unless I change some not very-simple things structurally that would be the case (while it's trivial to assign sub-states to specific workers - it's not trivial to keep some workers from idling, if they don't work out of a single task queue (I'm processing a stream).